# How can I load an image on Python Pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Helllo

I am using command line to get introduced to Pillow.

```
from PIL import Image
myImage = Image.open(green_leaves.jpg)
```

gives me the following error

```
name 'green_leaves' is not defined
```

Could you help me?

Thank you

Hugo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filename argument is a string, and should be in quotes:

```
myImage = Image.open("green_leaves.jpg")
```

Without the quotes, Python looks for the attribute `jpg` of the object referenced by name `green_leaves`, which does not exist; hence the `NameError`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the file name between quotes, to be parsed as a string:

```
myImage = Image.open("green_leaves.jpg")
```

Your code attempts to access to a variable `green_leaves` (before acceding to its attribute `jpg`) which doesn't exist...